# GAE cron retry parameters

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cron

[GAE page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsIdV.png)

As suggested by GAE, I have added the retry parameter as(copied from the GAE website):

```
     - retry_parameters
       min_backoff_seconds: 2.5
       max_doublings: 5
```

But when I'm trying to deploy my project, it gives the following error:

"Error parsing yaml file:

mapping values are not allowed here
  in "/path/to/my/project/cron.yaml", line x, column xx"

line x is at

```
    min_backoff_seconds: 2.5
```

any help?

Answer (score 3):

Remove the hyphen from `retry_parameters`. Also, the parameters to `retry_parameters` should be indented by one more level.

```
cron:
- description: daily reports and exports
  url: /admin/reports/reportsdaily
  schedule: every 10 mins
  retry_parameters:
    min_backoff_seconds: 2.5
    max_doublings: 5
```

Comment: thanks, i actually ask on GAE groups and got the same answer : [Google Group link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/Uea7dkc7alc)

Answer (score 0):

That's not valid yaml, from what I can tell. Assuming it's the example on https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron. Try adding a colon after `retry_parameters`. The parameters to retry_parameters should be indented by one more level.

```
cron:
- description: retry demo
  url: /retry
  schedule: every 10 mins
- retry_parameters:
    min_backoff_seconds: 2.5
    max_doublings: 5
```

Comment: tried this, and still got the same error 'Error parsing yaml file:
mapping values are not allowed here in "/path/to/my/project/cron.yaml", line x, column xx'

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake: it should probably be like this. (I have updated my original answer instead)